# What's the summary probability of an event if it increases over time?

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble calculating this one.

Say there are two steps an event occurs with certain probability:

1. 60%
2. 70%

What is the probability that an event occurs by the time second step is reached?

At first I automatically multiplied both probabilities, but it doesn't make sense (as the result is about ~40-50%). If there's 60% something happens on the first step, and 70% that it happens on the second step, the total probability should be higher than both (but not higher than 100% obviously). What have I missed?

Comment: 60%+(1-60%).70%=88%.

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate the rule this calculation is based upon?

Comment: Note, that we must have that the steps are independent. If for instance we have, $A_i$ is event at $i$-th step $\mathbb{P}(A_2 \mid A_1 ) = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_2 \mid A_1^C ) =\frac{1}{4}$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(A_2) = \mathbb{P}(A_2 \mid A_1) \mathbb{P}(A_1) + \mathbb{P}(A_2 \mid A_1^C) \mathbb{P}(A_1^C) = 0.6 + 0.1 = 0.7$$ and $$\mathbb{P}( \textrm{something happens at the first 2 steps} ) = \mathbb{P}(A_1) + \mathbb{P}(A_1^C) \mathbb{P}(A_2 \mid A_1^C) = 0.6+0.1=0.7$$

Comment: @Did could you please explain how you did that and how I could calculate probabilities with more steps?

Comment: First term: probability that the event happens on first step. Second term: probability that the event does not happen at first step *and* does happen on second step. Preassumed: independence in the sense that the probability that the event happens (or not) on the first step has no influence on the probability that it happens on the the second step.

Comment: Arthmost: What @drhab said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the probability that the event happens in the first step or that it does not but happens in the second step.  This is the probability that the event happens in at least one of the steps.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B) & =\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(A^\complement)\mathsf P(B) \\ & = (0.60) + (1-0.60)(0.70) \\ & = 0.88 \end{align}$$

Alternatively, you want the probability that the event does not *not* happen in both steps. (The complement of the conjunction of complements).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B) & = 1-\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement) \\ & = 1-(1-0.60)(1-0.70) \\ & = 0.88\end{align}$$

(This assumes that the probable occurrence of events in each step are independent.)

Comment: Hey there. Thank you very much, your answer explained the case to me pretty well. However, I've a harder case now for consideration. What if there are 3 steps now, and an event might occur twice in total (once in any of them)? say, 50%-60%-70%.

Comment: @Arthmost: Are you looking for "exactly twice" or "at least twice"?  The former is: $$(0.50)\big((0.60)(1.00-0.70)+(1.00-0.60)(0.70)\big)+(1.00-0.50)(0.60)(0.70)$$  The later is: $$(0.50)\big((0.60)(1.00-0.70)+(1.00-0.60)(0.70)\big)+(1.00)(0.60)(0.70)$$

Comment: Well, in both cases the event can only happen once and twice, respectively so I believe it's 'exactly twice'. Do I get it right that to calculate such a probability (that the event happens exactly X times), I just need to summarize combinations of outcomes I am looking for? I can see in your first formula that you're just varying the two successful steps. I'm asking as I want to understand the big picture to be able to solve harder cases. Also, this means that your original response is no longer correct. It should be (1-0.6)(0.7)+(1-0.7)(0.6), right? The result doesn't seem correct though..

Comment: @Arthmost $(1-0.6)(0.7)+(1-0.7)(0.6)$ is the probability of the event happening *exactly* once in those two times.  The original answer is for happening *at least* once (thus it includes the possibility of happening twice; once each time).

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate why there's (1.00)*(0.60)*(0.70) in your second formula for the case with 3 steps?

Comment: I was wrong in assuming I need the probability of an event happening exactly X times. This limits the possibilities and thus the resulting probability is way too low. Apparently in each case I need the probability of it happening at least X times in a given number of the steps, and I need to understand how to calculate it depending on the number of steps/events.